# Startup problems - Dual-boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: dual-boot

I bought a new Notebook some days ago and used to use Linux on it. As it was with an original Windows 8.1, I decided to create an dual-boot because I didn't actually wanted to lose the free license by formating the entire hard drive.

Well, I used the CD and selected the first option of instalation (The one that configurates dual-boot automatically) when it asked what partition did I wanted to put on the OS.

So, everything OK, I installed it. However, after I boot the computer I always get 4 options:

1-) ubuntu
2-) Advanced Options for Ubuntu
3-) Windows Boot Manager (in dev/sda1) 
4-) System Setup

When I click "ubuntu", Linux starts, everything normal.

However, when I click "Windows Boot Manager (in dev/sda1)", Windows will start. Wasn't it suppose to open a boot manager where I should select if I want to start Linux or Windows?

I went to the System Setup to change the order of the Boot. If I put ubuntu before Windows Boot Manager, the computer will give me that 4 options above. However, if I put Windows Boot Manager first, it won't even ask what OS I want - it will start Windows directly.

Is that right? I think something is wrong but I can't tell why. I never used Linux before. What should I do to make the Windows Boot Manager work properly?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

windows boot manager won't recognize ubuntu and so only loads up windows, and did you turn off fast boot in windows?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did have secure boot and fast boot disabled. I already fixed the problem, thanks anyway!

Comment: great! and welcome to linux :)